# How to show 'typing..' text when user starts typing text, and also to show 'stopped typing' text same like whats app application

Tags: android

I'm working on chat application,so i want to show a text **typing..** when someone starts replying  to another and also show text **stopped typing** when user stopped typing. H ow to achieve this logic i have tried using text change listener to my edit text but it displaying 'typing..' when user already stopped typing. **My requirement is 'typing...' text should be displayed only when user presses the key on keyboard, if he stops pressing i need to display 'stopped typing..'**

here is logic what i have used

```
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString()) && s.toString().trim().length() == 1) {

                Log.e("AAAAAAAAAAA", "Typing.....");

                typingStarted = true;

            } else if (s.toString().trim().length() == 0 && typingStarted) {

                Log.e("AAAAAAAAAAA", "Stopped Typing.....");

                typingStarted = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jake Wharton RXBinding library: https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding
You need to emit text changes events and listen to them. As long as something is emitting you can have your value as `is typing...`. In your subscription, you can have a timer for example for 1 second if nothing emits changing the value to `Stopped typing`.

```
YourEditText.textChanges()
            .subscribe { 
            YourTextView.text = "is typing..."
            }
```

and you can have something like:

```
YourTextView.textChanges()
            .skipInitialValue()
            .debounce(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe { YourTextView.text = "Stopped typing" }
```

This might not be the best answer, but I think you can get the idea from it.